# Using custom setting variable directly in a SOQL statement (System.QueryException: No such column xx entity)

Tags: apex, soql, customsetting

I want to use custom setting in direct soql statement, but it turns out not working.
Because of the requirement, I can't add another field in that object.

The only thing I can do is to use Custom Setting as it might be changed frequently.

```
Error : System.QueryException: No such column 'defaultPost' on entity
```

Coding:

```
MySetting__c mysetting = MySetting__c.getValues('DefaultPost');
Boolean defaultPost = mysetting.booleanValue__c;

String soql = 'SELECT myfield__c'
              + ', Name'
          + ' FROM my_object__c'
          + ' WHERE my_object__c.status__c = \'Open\''
              + ' AND (my_object__c.post__c = true OR defaultPost =:true)';
```

How can I put Custom Setting in the query which will allow me to change frequently?

I don't want to change the coding so many times for every changes. That is my main purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a variable as a filter in SOQL, it must be a field on the object that you're comparing against.

Why don't you just wrap your filter in an `IF` statement instead?

```
MySetting__c mysetting = MySetting__c.getValues('DefaultPost');
Boolean defaultPost = mysetting.booleanValue__c;

// If your default setting is true, you want to get the reocrds regardless if my_object__c.post__c is true (according to your logic), so there is no need to filter
String soql = 'SELECT myfield__c'
              + ', Name'
          + ' FROM my_object__c'
          + ' WHERE my_object__c.status__c = \'Open\'';

if (defaultPost == false)
{
    // You only need to include records where my_object__c.post__c is true when the custom setting is false
    soql += ' AND my_object__c.post__c = true';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bachovski, I came up with idea same as you. For now, I can only use this approach. Will accept your answer after 3 minutes.